# Apple ID - Email Address Change

Tags: icloud

I am thoroughly confused by the Apple ID, Email Address, User Name, iCloud conurbation it is to me an almost impenetrable mess. The best answer I have found here is below and I would appreciate some clarification. What I want to do is change the @outlook address I was forced to use to set up Apple ID to an @icloud address. The clarification I need is in the original answer below, the reason is I am conbverting an 86 year old man converting from Microsoft to his first iMac 21 last week! and I need to keep it very simple, trying to explain why he needs a microsoft email address to access his Apple ID is beyond my powers - and his. So I want to set it up with an @icloud address - please help 8-)

The answer I found that explains all except the crucial bits is below in quotes, question mixed in for clarity and context.

**"Sign out of iCloud, the iTunes & App store, FaceTime, Find My Friends, Find My iPhone,and iMessage on each device that uses your Apple ID."**

OK no problem I don't have any of that,the iMac 21 is the only Apple he has.

**"Sign in to your Apple ID account page."**

Fine used @outlook address I had to set up specially to get a Apple ID

**"In the Account section, click Edit > Change Email Address. Enter the email address you want to use as your Apple ID."**

I want to use an i-Cloud address - how and where do I get an i-cloud address set up?

**"A verification code will be sent to your new email address."**

Yeah brilliant what new address how can I use an email address (@icloud) I have not set up and have no password or login for?

**"Enter the verification code from the email into the fields provided and start using your updated Apple ID. Didn't get the email?"**

Er no - I have no icloud address yet to get a verification on?

You see the reason for my utter confusion - I thought Linux could be a bit tricky but this bit of Apple Lore is a total mystery seems I am missing a fundamental fact here, does an icloud address get set up automatically and how do I access the thing???. TIA  Jonah

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an @icloud.com address by following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2620?locale=en_US).

Keep in mind that you can't change an iCloud address once set up.